# Using angularjs2 with jquery?

Tags: jquery, angular

Most of the guides say that it is not a problem just download jquery and the typings file and then edit the typings file to remove the export `$` part

The problem with that is that I need to export `$` since the plugins I'm going to use expect jquery to be defined as `$`

How can I use jquery with angularjs2 with exporting the global `$` jquery variable

Comment: @WojciechKwiatek no its not good because they remove the '$' from the exports or I didn't understand it well and '$' will still refer to jquery? doesnt angularjs2 uses '$' for something else so we cant bind to it jquery?

Comment: The answer which is there is about deleting typings for that. You can still use jquery with a script tag or attach jquery imported from npm to window.$

Comment: @WojciechKwiatek oh I see can you explain to me why did we need to remove the `$` from the typings? which module in angularjs2 uses that? and if I just include a <script> tag to jquery in my page which will bind `$` to my window object, will it work fine with angularjs2?

Comment: From the link: 
"tslint will give you an error since $ conflicts with protractor Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'"

Angular should not complain about global $ variable.